# ImportError: cannot import name normalize_data_format

Tags: python, tensorflow, github, keras, importerror

I am very new to use github. I have installed github in ubuntu 16.04, I installed python 2.7.12, tensorflow 1.9 and keras. I want to use my own custom activation and optimizer in keras RNN. I searched in web and came to know i need to install keras-contrib package to use advanced activation and custom activation function.

So, I install the keras-contrib from github. But I don't know how to work with it and how to run the program using keras-contrib.

But i tried with following commands

```
 git clone https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git
 cd keras-contrib
 python setup.py install
```

then I tried with this following code

```
 from keras.models import Sequential
 from keras.layers import Dense
 import numpy as np
 from keras_contrib.layers.advanced_activations import PELU
```

it showing the following error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "keras_contrib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import layers
   File "keras_contrib/layers/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .convolutional import *
   File "keras_contrib/layers/convolutional.py", line 15, in <module>
    from keras.utils.conv_utils import normalize_data_format
  ImportError: cannot import name normalize_data_format
```

Anyone please check this error and help me to sort out this error.

Answer (score 5):

I update the keras contribute source code installed in my linux. Follow the changes:

https://github.com/ekholabs/keras-contrib/commit/0dac2da8a19f34946448121c6b9c8535bfb22ce2

Now, it works well.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I installed keras 2.2.2 version using the following command and problem solved.

`pip install -q keras==2.2.2`

Refer this PR.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib/pull/292

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. The problem  is that normalize_data_format function was moved to keras.backend.common from keras.utils.conv_utils in later versions of keras. You can use

```
import keras
```

and then in your code use

```
keras.utils.conv_utils.normalize_data_format
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that in keras version 2.6.0 the normalize function is not lost, it is just "stored" in a file "np_utils.py", so what we need to do is just change
"

```html
from keras.utils import normalize
```

to

```html
from keras.utils.np_utils import normalize
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be because the keras_contrib you have downloaded is not compatible with updated version of keras. Check this link https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/conv_utils.py

There is no function here like normalise_data_format, that is where it is throwing error.

Comment: Thank you Ms. Upasana. But how to overcome this.

Comment: Either you can try downgrading keras package or edit conv_utils.py file. 
For editing conv_utils.py of your downloaded keras package, copy function from here and paste
 https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/keras-2/keras/utils/conv_utils.py

Comment: facing the same issue here, @KVijayaprabakaran were you able to fix the issue finally? Using which of this answer? Could you please let us know? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It must be because the keras_contrib you have downloaded is not compatible with updated version of keras. Check this link https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/conv_utils.py

It does not work...

Answer (score 0):

This bug is reported and fixed here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib/issues/291

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 10 system and in Colaboratory, using Python 3.7, I solved this problem updating Keras and installing git version of keras-contrib.

```
pip install -q keras==2.2.2
pip install git+https://www.github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib.git
```

Check your Keras version with

```
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

Comment: I have tried your solution for same environment but its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by using this :

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import normalize
```

instead of :

```
from keras.utils import normalize
```